# Data truncated for column 'last_trade_time' at row 1 for datetime field

Tags: python, mysql

For the given set of code

```
query1 = 'UPDATE orders SET last_trade_time = %s WHERE tradingsymbol like %s '
query2 = 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;'
xx='TATACHEM'

pointer.execute(query2)
pointer.execute(query1, (ltt, xx,) )


db.commit()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'last_trade_time' at row 1
```

LTT Contains the datetime value as shown:

[image: LTT]

Comment: Look precise SQL text sent to MySQL (see in General Log).

Comment: Unable to find general log file

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this.

It seems that for the 'last_trade_time' column I had assigned a value of int. The size of int is 4 bytes. The value of datetime passed in mycase was 19 bytes. Hence the data was getting truncated.

The length of a column can be found by:

```
select LENGTH(last_trade_time) FROM orders;
```

Which gave me the length of 19 bytes